# Send private message to a slackbot without other users of the workspace seeing it

Tags: node.js, npm, slack

How can i send a private message to a bot other without users seeing it on the channel?

Im using node js and the module slackbots. And each time i communicate with the bot it goes something like this: "@robot hello" but everybody on the chat sees it.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not a direct message, but a so called "mention" in a channel, which is always visible by everyone else in the same channel.

But you can also send a real direct message to a bot user. It works the same like sending a direct message to any user. e.g. click on the plus next to "Direct Messages", select the bot user from the list and click on go. Now you got a direct messaging channel with that user which is 100% private.

Your bot obviously needs to be ready to receive messages via DM in order to respond correctly. e.g if your are using Slack's [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) you need to subscribe to [`message.im`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im) to receive posts in the direct message channel to your bot.

Check out [this help desk page](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/212281468-Direct-messages-and-group-DMs) on how to send direct messages.

Another approach to communicate "secretly" with your bot user in a channel is [slash commands](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands), e.g. by posting `/mybot hi` in a channel. Both the slash command and respond from your app will not be visible to anyone else in the channel (that is default - but can be changed).

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. so there is no way in a public channel i can address a bot and that bot reply to me privately? without appearing on the general chat

Comment: Not with a mention. But you could of course use a slash command to address the bot . That would be invisible to the channel

Comment: could you exemplify please?

Comment: I added some examples and explanations to my answer